# Error when installing acconeer-python-exploration

Tags: python, python-3, packages, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am trying to install this on my Pi https://github.com/acconeer/acconeer-python-exploration .
There are some requirements written in the file requirements.txt that need to be installed first. I've installed them following the installation setup on the github and I was getting an error. So I've installed them manually one by one succesfully, except PyQt5. When trying to install PyQt5==5.15.2 with pip install PyQt5==5.15.2 or any of the versions I am getting the following error:

```
 Collecting PyQt5==5.15.2
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz3nv8pux
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4dki0smz/pyqt5_356672bf24d042f59cf05c55516088c2
    Complete output (35 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/bin/qmake -query
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 131, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        config_settings)
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 481, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 227, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 75, in apply_user_defaults
        self._get_qt_configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tym5j4lm/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 516, in _get_qt_configuration
        "v{0}".format(self.qt_version_str))
    sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz#sha256=372b08dc9321d1201e4690182697c5e7ffb2e0770e6b4a45519025134b12e4fc (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz3nv8pux Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5==5.15.2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt5==5.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing PyQt5 with apt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

Side note: The application in the repository is not intended to run on your Raspberry Pi but rather your PC.